# Add parameter to URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I have in my functions.php this function:

```
// rewrite the url
function my_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'demo/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=demo&p_id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrites_init' );

function my_build_demo_url($p_id)
{
$demo_url = add_query_arg( array('p_id' => $p_id, 'pagename' =>'demo'), get_home_url() );
return $demo_url;
}
```

In my page I have `<a href = "<?php echo my_build_demo_url($id)?>" ></a>` but I see `http://mysite.com/locale/?p_id=105&pagename=demo`.

NB: in my WordPress admin I have flushed the permalink.

Comment: What is your question? Your function seems to produce correct output, do you expect or want to achieve different result?

Comment: my question is why url isn't rewrited ?

Comment: Which URL? The one you are getting from `my_build_demo_url()` function?

Comment: rewrite rules parse incoming requests and translate pretty URLs to query vars, but you're not outputting a pretty URL with your `my_build_demo_url` function, your rewrite rule has nothing to do with this.